# how to handle parameters passed with getJSON to json file

Tags: php, jquery

can I ask about the structure for check-email-address.json file, ajax request and the php file that will handle the emailAddress parameter

```
$.getJSON("/check-email-address.json", { emailAddress: $("#newEmailAddress").val() })
```

Comment: Show us the PHP script you have tried with.

Comment: I don't have problem in php code, I just want to know where I supposed to recieve the parameter. Thank you.

Comment: In PHP, so show the PHP script you have. Don't leave us guessing as to what you want. Show what you have tried, and we can indicate where there might be problems. I suppose you know about `$_POST` and `$_GET`? Have you tried getting the argument with that? What did you get?

Comment: I have been trying for 3 days. yes I know about $_POST and $_GET. But my problem is : the url is a .json file. how can I recieve a parameter in a json file? and if I supposed to recieve the parameter in php file, how can I link between php file and json file. Thank you

Comment: It is very easy if the url .php file, but when the url .json file, where I supposed to recieve the parameter. I searched about an example but I didn't find any one. Thank you.

Comment: Just give the file a `.php` extension, and let PHP spit out the JSON. In jQuery you can specify that PHP file as the source for your JSON.

Comment: Do you mean file_name.json.php ? Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, use the file name where you have coded your PHP script. It does not even need to have `.json` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow PHP to do something, such as treating request parameters, you need a file with `.php` extension. However, this is not a problem. In your jQuery you can specify that PHP file as the source for your JSON. It does not need have the `.json` extension.

In PHP you would use the `$_GET` array to access the arguments like would do for any other page that receives arguments.

The script would look something like this -- this is just an example:

```
<?php
$email = $_GET['emailAddress'];
// We have some data...
$array = [ "address" => '1 baconstreet', "name" => 'John' ];
// Do something that influences the output based on argument
$array['mail'] = $email;
// Output JSON
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

If you save this file as `check-email-address.php`, you can call it like that in jQuery. You'll want to capture the response created by PHP, by providing a success callback function as third argument:

```
$.getJSON(
     "/check-email-address.php",
     { emailAddress: $("#newEmailAddress").val() },
     function (response) {
         // do something with the JSON:
         console.log(response);
     }
);
```

Comment: I have no problem with .php file. I'm asking about that code $.getJSON("/check-email-address.json", { emailAddress: $("#newEmailAddress").val() }). how does it working? Thank you

Comment: As I read your question, you did also ask about PHP. I have added information about the jQuery part as well, but your question is rather broad. What specifically you have an issue with?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  I was asking about how can I send parameter to .json file. and how can I recieve this parameter either in php or in ajax  ( I don't know ) because this code is already working and I have no idea about files behind . I was asking if there was a new technique or a trick. Thank you so much

Comment: yes it all clear now, Thank you so much.

Comment: OK, I was not sure :) You're welcome.